# Opposite of ->EndsWith()

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

What is the opposite of the string comparison

thisString->EndsWith("String")

If it does not end with...

Comment: Using terms like "opposite of" in relation to code is a really, really bad idea. It's like when non-programmers say "And" when they mean "Or", etc.

Comment: Surely does and doesn't are opposites?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Good comment Armentage

Answer (score 6):

```
!thisString->EndsWith("String");
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you mean by "opposite", but there is a StartsWith method. Alternatively if you're looking for whether it doesn't end with you could just negate the value returned by EndsWith. Hope this helps, and that I'm understanding the question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to detail your question a bit, my friend.

Either you are looking for :

```
StartsWith("string");
```

^ refers to the beginning of the string

or

```
!thisString->EndsWith("string");
```

^ you will use this to check if the string does not end with "string"

Answer (score 0):

Verbose:

```
if (thisString->EndsWith("String") == false)
{
    // does not end with
}
```

Terse:

```
if (!thisString->EndsWith("String"))
{
    // ditto
}
```